# Copying C++ objects from an iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, iterator

I'm trying to build an array of objects, using an iterator over a collection to get the values.

The current code is:

```
Object array[n]; //n is defined higher up the program
int index = 0;
for (iterator i = container.begin(), ie = container.end(); i != ie;++i) {
  Object f = *i;
  array[index] = f;
  index++;
}
```

I've abstracted some stuff away, Object and container are classes from a 3rd party library.

This code would work, but Object's assignment operator has been deleted and its copy constructor is private.

Further points:

While I can of course easily build something of type Object*[], it's not compatible with a library call later in the code.

container has no 'to array' method, or anything similar.

Comment: If `Object` isn't copyable, then whoever wrote `Object` specifically doesn't want you to do this. Quite possibly a copy wouldn't work correctly anyway. So you either have to stop trying to do this (perhaps keep an array of `Object*` instead and find a way of avoiding the library call that can't work with that), or else you have to declare them wrong and re-write `Object`.

Comment: *Object's assignment operator has been deleted and its copy constructor is private* seems like someone doesnt want you to make a copy of this `Object` ...

Comment: Has `Object` got move-constructor and/or move-assignment operator?

Answer (score 0):

For others finding this topic by searching for your title: You would copy from the iterator exactly as you attempted to do, if the non-copyable constraint did not apply.

To answer your question:
If you find a class named "Object" in a third party *C++* library, you should instantly throw that 3rd party library into the trash can and find an alternative written by someone who knows C++, instead of someone who is so in love with Java (or another language that has a common base Object), that they decided to try to mimic its behavior in a language where that behavior makes no sense. I'm not trying to trash talk, but this is a serious red flag.

However, as was said, if object is not copy constructable, then there is more than likely something in the implementation of Object, that the author of the class is aware of ,that you aren't, that prohibits copying. Trying to work around it is asking for bugs.

My first thought would be to contact the author of the library and query why they deemed the object non-copyable and what could be done for your particular usage.

If you simply want to move instances of Objects from one array to another, consider containing pointers to Objects or perhaps shared_ptr to Objects rather than the Object class itself, but be wary and understand that you are passing around pointers to the one and only instance of the particular object.

Comment: clearly `Object` is not the actual name in the library, just used for purposes of this question